# How do properly set up VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, vulkan, undefined-reference

I have tried to get this to work using several methods and no matter what I keep getting:

```
/usr/local/include/vulkan/vulkan.hpp:2453: undefined reference to `vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT'

/usr/local/include/vulkan/vulkan.hpp:2548: undefined reference to `vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT'
```

Here is what I currently have (hopefully this is enough code to diagnose the problem)

```
// destroy and create funcs
PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT pfnVkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT;
PFN_vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT pfnVkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT;

VKAPI_ATTR VkResult VKAPI_CALL vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT* pCreateInfo, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT* pMessenger)
{
  return pfnVkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(instance, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pMessenger);
}

VKAPI_ATTR void VKAPI_CALL vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT messenger, VkAllocationCallbacks const * pAllocator)
{
  return pfnVkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(instance, messenger, pAllocator);
}
```

```
// instance creation stuff here ...
createUniqueInstance(...);
//


// init and setup debug utils messenger
    pfnVkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT>(
        instance->getProcAddr("vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT"));
    if (!pfnVkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT) {
        exit_(1, "GetInstanceProcAddr: Unable to find pfnVkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT function.");
    }

    pfnVkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT>(
        instance->getProcAddr("vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT"));
    if (!pfnVkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT) {
        exit_(1, "GetInstanceProcAddr: Unable to find pfnVkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT function.");
    }


    vk::DebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagsEXT severityFlags(
        vk::DebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT::eWarning |
        vk::DebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT::eError);
    vk::DebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT messageTypeFlags(
        vk::DebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagBitsEXT::eGeneral |
        vk::DebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagBitsEXT::ePerformance |
        vk::DebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagBitsEXT::eValidation);
    debugUtilsMessenger = instance->createDebugUtilsMessengerEXTUnique(vk::DebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT(
        {}, severityFlags, messageTypeFlags, &vk::su::debugUtilsMessengerCallback));
```

// note the vk::su::debugUtilsMessengerCallback is from here:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/blob/master/samples/utils/utils.hpp

The 'createUniqueInstance' function is also more or less derived from the createInstance func in the file above. there are no modifications that *should* have any affect the debug utils messenger stuff though.

What am I doing wrong that I keep getting the linker errors.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not calling e.g. ```vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT``` somewhere in your code? Your function is named ```pfnVkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT``` so it seems odd that the error message does not refer to that. For the Khronos sample you're referring too (which was written by me) we're using a dynamic loader (volk) so we can directly access the vk variants without manually loading the function pointers.

Comment: No not calling `vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT` at all. I wonder if maybe I should add volk now. Maybe thats the problem? Although I have tried it other ways without using the `pfnVkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT` instead tried like on https://vulkan-tutorial.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the `vulkan.hpp` C++ header. It assumes that all functions are present, which is not the case for extension functions (that aren't part of the core). So you need to pass a dynamic dispatcher to the messenger callback creation function.

I'm not using `vulkan.hpp` myself, but it should look something like this in your case:

```
debugUtilsMessenger = instance->createDebugUtilsMessengerEXTUnique(vk::DebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT(
    {}, severityFlags, messageTypeFlags, &vk::su::debugUtilsMessengerCallback), nullptr, vk::DispatchLoaderDynamic{ *instance });
```

Note the `vk::DispatchLoaderDynamic` passed as the last parameter.

Details on this can be found [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp#extensions--per-device-function-pointers).